# How to use setTimeout for removing items from cart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, settimeout

My e-commerce site contains Products(view) and Cart(view) and when I add items to cart I have button "Remove". I want to set Timeout when I click Remove button, which removes the product. Remove button works only when I change the page and come back, but I want to add Timeout and to remove it immediately.

This is my logic in remove function. I add timeout here. I have removing key in object initially on false; This code is located in my store.js file (objects seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF2K9.png));

```js
export function removeFromCart(id){
    cart[id].removing = true; // Set removing flag to trigger animation
    const index = cart.findIndex(item => item === id);
    if (index !== -1) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            cart.splice(index, 1); // Remove item after animation
        }, 500); // Set the animation duration (milliseconds)
}
```

This is my code in CartMain.vue

```html
<tr
  v-for="item in cartItems"
  :key="item.name"
  :class="{ 'remove-animation': item.removing }"
></tr>
```

And this is my style also

```css
.remove-animation {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease; /* Adjust the animation properties as needed */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: when a page requires navigating away and back to see updated values, it's a sign that reactivity is broken.  what we don't know is what is (or is supposed to be) reactive in your code.  show how your different objects like `cart` and `cartItems` are defined.  also show how they are related. why would splicing `cart` affect the v-for which uses `cartItems`?

Comment: This is my code in CartMain.vue                                                                                     let cartItems = ref(cart);

console.log(cart)

const cartItemss = cart;

const items = computed(() => cartItems.value.length);
  And also i have this function                                                                                                        const removeItem = (id) => {
  removeFromCart(id);
}

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem instead of detached snippets, also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . It's expected to work as is if cart[id].... is reactive. Considering that cartItems is reactive and cart isn't, it's unclear why you operate on cart and not cartItems, potentially this needs to be fixed